# Relay voltage at higher voltage with no current

Tags: voltage, power, relay

If you use a 220V relay to switch 400 volt but without drawing any current (no current will pass through the relay) is it ok?

Comment: If no current passes through, why do you need the relay at all?

Comment: Analogy: "My engine is redlined at 5000 RPM. If I rev it to 10,000 RPM with no load will it be OK?". Answer in this case and your case is NO NO NO, No No No, no no no no no .... . || [Solid state relays are more likely to die at 2 x Vrated than are electromechanical ones.

Comment: I suggest that you **think** about what happens regarding voltages and currents when a switch (a relay is just a switch that is controlled by another electrical signal) is 1) open and when that switch is 2) closed. So the 220V rating means: "There shall never-ever be more than 220V across this the contacts of this relay's switch". When does that apply? When the switch is open or closed? Does current flow?

Answer (score 11):

No, because the voltage rating is more about insulation between the conductors than it is about the characteristics of the load.

Comment: Even when using solid state relay??

Comment: @MohammadALrefaie *especially*!!! Seriously, what do you think ratings are for?

Comment: Not only that, you can't use a relay rated for only 100VAC with 100VDC. Also, no you can't put relays in series.

Comment: @MohammadALrefaie It is actually even more important not to exceed the voltage rating on solid state relays.